# Convert array of formatted strings into an array of arrays

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql, text-parsing

How to convert an array from a Postgres query to array variable in Laravel?

My [image: postgres array structure]

I have result var_dump from Laravel:

```
0 => array:1 [
    "order_itemset" => "{8,11}"
  ]
1 => array:1 [
"order_itemset" => "{8,12}"
  ]
2 => array:1 [
"order_itemset" => "{17,10}"
  ]
]
```

How can I get the data and store the data to array variable?

like this

```
$data = [['8', '11'], ['8', '12'], ['17', '10']];
```

Comment: did you try `foreach` ?

Comment: nope, im newb can you explain how to use foreach for my case ? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here.

You can simplify this code if your postgres query returns an array "[8,11]" instead of a "sort-of" JSON "{8,11}"

```
<?php
$values = array_column($your_data, 'order_itemset');
$values = array_map(function ($v) {
    preg_match("/^\{(.+)\}$/", $v, $matches);
    if ($matches[1]) {
        return explode(',', $matches[1]);
    }
    return null;
}, $values);
print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach

```
$original_array = $your_array;   //Your base array that you showed us on your Question
$base_array = array();

foreach($original_array as $original)
{
    $child_array = array();

    foreach($original->order_itemset as $a)
    {
        $child_array[] = $a;
    }
    $base_array[] = $child_array;
    unset($child_array);
}

die($base_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the rows and convert the string values to valid JSON and then parse to get int-type values. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Lpp88)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => json_decode(strtr($row['order_itemset'], '{}', '[]')),
        $array
    )
);
```

Or if you don't mind string-type values, you can trim the outer curly braces and call `explode()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/2e3np)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => explode(',', trim($row['order_itemset'], '{}')),
        $array
    )
);
```